# undefined reference to ... when compiling ros node

Tags: c++, opencv, g++, ros, catkin

I'm trying to write a ROS-Node which uses OpenCV nonfree components (SURF). I have trouble compiling the package using catkin_make:

```
//usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so: undefined reference to `cv::ocl::integral(cv::ocl::oclMat const&, cv::ocl::oclMat&)'
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(homography_test)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
)

catkin_package(

)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
# include_directories(include)
include_directories(
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    /usr/local/include
    /usr/include
    /usr/include/gstreamer-1.0
    /usr/include/glib-2.0
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
)

## Declare a cpp executable
#add_executable(display_image src/display_image_node.cpp)
add_executable(homography src/sample.cpp)

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable/library
## as an example, message headers may need to be generated before nodes
#add_dependencies(homography_test homography_test_generate_messages_cpp)

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(
    homography

    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}

    gstreamer-1.0
    gobject-2.0
    glib-2.0

    opencv_nonfree
    opencv_calib3d
    opencv_contrib
    opencv_core
    opencv_features2d
    opencv_flann
    opencv_gpu
    opencv_highgui
    opencv_imgproc
    opencv_legacy
    opencv_ml
    opencv_objdetect
    opencv_ocl
    opencv_photo
    opencv_stitching
    opencv_superres
    opencv_ts
    opencv_video
    opencv_videostab
    rt
    pthread
    m
    dl
)

link_directories(/usr/local/lib)
```

But if I manually compile the same code, but not as ROS-node, everything works.

Comment: you should edit your post by adding the `CMakeList.txt` at least, but have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553659/linking-opencv-nonfree-components-sift-features-and-ocl-specifically) first.

Comment: I´v already read that post but that didn't helped me.

Comment: What does the compile line look like when you add VERBOSE=1 to your make execution?

Comment: i guess, you need opencv in the find_package() section

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the `opencv_ocl` library is not being linked properly. Also, you can simplify your `CMakeLists.txt` file a lot by using `find_package` to get your OpenCV configuration. Try adding those lines to your `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED core ocl)
include_directories(SYSTEM ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(homography ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} )
```

You need to specify which OpenCV libraries you want to include in the `find_package`. I listed only `core` and `ocl` since `ocl` seems to be what you need, but others might be needed as well.